# How to remove repeated node details in xml?

Tags: c#, xml

I have xml file like following.

```
<Root>
      <Main Name="Install">
        <Details>Success</Details>
        <Maintain>Install period</Maintain>
      </Main>
    <Main Name="Uninstall">
        <Details>failure</Details>
        <Maintain>uninstall period</Maintain>
      </Main>
     <Main Name="Discard">
        <Details>failure</Details>
        <Maintain>discard period</Maintain>
      </Main>
     <Main Name="Install">
        <Details>Done</Details>
        <Maintain>Got Output</Maintain>
      </Main>
    </Root>
```

I need only last latest update to print in xml.

I've used following code and found output.

```
XDocument xDoc1 = XDocument.Load(inputFileName);

        var elems = xDoc1.Element("Root").Elements("Main");

        XElement xInstall = elems.LastOrDefault(a => a.Attribute("Name").Value == "Install");
        XElement xUninstall = elems.LastOrDefault(a => a.Attribute("Name").Value == "Uninstall");
        XElement xDiscard = elems.LastOrDefault(a => a.Attribute("Name").Value == "Discard");

        XDocument xdoc2 = new XDocument();

        xdoc2.Add(
            new XElement("Root", new XElement[]
            {
                xInstall,
                xDiscard,
                xUninstall
            })
        );

        xdoc2.Save(ouputFileName);
```

But while using this same logic in foreach loop I can't get correct output. My code is,

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
string xmlLocation = @"C:\Input.xml";
xml.Load(xmlLocation);
XmlNodeList MainNameList = xml.SelectNodes("/Root/Main");

XDocument xDoc1 = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Input.xml");

var elems = xDoc1.Element("Root").Elements("Main");
XDocument xdoc2 = new XDocument();
xdoc2.Add(new XElement("Root"));
foreach (XmlNode MainNode in MainNameList)
{
    string mainName = MainNode.Attributes[0].Value;
    XElement MainNode = elems.LastOrDefault(a => a.Attribute("Name").Value == mainName);


    xdoc2.Root.Add(new XElement("Root", new XElement(MainNode)));

}

xdoc2.Save(@"C:\Output.xml");
```

the output came like following:

```
<Root>
  <Main Name="Install">
    <Details>Success</Details>
    <Maintain>Naveen</Maintain>
  </Main>
  <Main Name="Uninstall">
    <Details>failure</Details>
    <Maintain>uninstall period</Maintain>
  </Main>
  <Main Name="Discard">
    <Details>failure</Details>
    <Maintain>discard period</Maintain>
  </Main>
  <Main Name="Install">
    <Details>Success</Details>
    <Maintain>Naveen</Maintain>
  </Main>
</Root>
```

But I need output like following:

```
<Root>
 <Main Name="Uninstall">
   <Details>failure</Details>
    <Maintain>uninstall period</Maintain>
 </Main>
 <Main Name="Discard">
    <Details>failure</Details>
    <Maintain>discard period</Maintain>
 </Main>
<Main Name="Install">
    <Details>Done</Details>
    <Maintain>Got Output</Maintain>
 </Main>
</Root>
```

What is the mistake i had on my code? Please help me on this for get correct output by using foreach loop. Because I had so many main elements in my xml. thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all your code wouldn't compile because of line `XElement MainNode = elems.LastOrDefault(a => a.Attribute("Name").Value == mainName);` as your foreach also declares variable with the same name.

Comment: Is output order important for you?

Comment: Is it OK if it will be "Install" - "Discard" - "Uninstall"?

Comment: output order was not important. "Install" - "Discard" - "Uninstall" is ok for me. @YeldarKurmangaliyev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you simply output the last element with name "X" every time you find an element with name "X". However, you don't remember if you have outputed it or not.

You can simply do this by utilizing `List<string>` and remembering which items you have outputed.

At the same time, this result can be easily achieved by utulizing LINQ, grouping items and extracting the last one from each group:

```
XDocument xDoc1 = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Input.xml");

var elemsNew = xDoc1.Element("Root").Elements("Main")
    .GroupBy(x => x.Attribute("Name").Value)
    .Select(g => g.Last())
    .ToArray();

XDocument xDoc2 = new XDocument(new XElement("Root", elemsNew));
xDoc2.Save(@"C:\Output.xml");
```

Comment: I was thinking of a GroupBy, but he was wanting help with his foreach loop. Nice though.

Comment: Am I able to get this same output by using xmldocument(using system.xml)? Is there any possible by xmldocument? @Yeldar

Comment: @GioFrog Nope, `XmlDocument` does not support LINQ. Why would you want to use `XmlDocument`? Use `XDocument`, it is better and more convenient.

Comment: Ya I understand. But I would like to know this operation available in xmldocument also. That's why I'm asked. Will It worked in xmldocument? If yes how to do that?..@YeldarKurmangaliyev

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet would ignore all the duplicate and select the last element if there is any duplicate node in the xml (having attribute name duplicated).

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
string xmlLocationInput = @"C:\Users\jprabadiya\Desktop\Input.xml";
string xmlLocationOutput = @"C:\Users\jprabadiya\Desktop\Output.xml";
xml.Load(xmlLocationInput);
XDocument xDoc1 = XDocument.Load(xmlLocationInput);

var elems = xDoc1.Element("Root").Elements("Main"); 
var nodeList = elems.GroupBy(d => d.Attribute("Name").Value).Select(d => d.Last()).ToList();

XDocument xdoc2 = new XDocument();
xdoc2.Add(new XElement("Root"));
xdoc2.Root.Add(nodeList);

xdoc2.Save(xmlLocationOutput);
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <Main Name="Install">
    <Details>Done</Details>
    <Maintain>Got Output</Maintain>
  </Main>
  <Main Name="Uninstall">
    <Details>failure</Details>
    <Maintain>uninstall period</Maintain>
  </Main>
  <Main Name="Discard">
    <Details>failure</Details>
    <Maintain>discard period</Maintain>
  </Main>
</Root>
```

Comment: Am I able to get this same output by using xmldocument(using system.xml)? Is there any possible by xmldocument? @Jenish

Comment: No my question is instead of using xdocument, is there any option available by using xmldocument? @Jenish

Answer (score 0):

You're using two different XML libraries, I'll simplify it to the Linq2XML.

```
XDocument xDoc1 = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Input.xml");
var elems = xDoc1.Descendants("Main");

// Get all the main names in the input file (1 of each)
string[] names = elems
    .Select(main => main.Attribute("Name").Value)
    .Distinct()
    .ToArray();

XDocument xdoc2 = new XDocument();
XElement root;
xdoc2.Add(root = new XElement("Root"));
foreach (string name in names)
{
    XElement node = elems
        .LastOrDefault(a => a.Attribute("Name").Value == name);
    root.Add(new XElement(node));
}

xdoc2.Save(@"C:\Output.xml");
```

Comment: Am I able to get this same output by using xmldocument(using system.xml)? Is there any possible by xmldocument? @Chuck

Comment: @GioFrog Probably, I just don't know the older `XmlDocument` style of coding.

Comment: Okay friend. Thanks for your reply. @Chuck